Lévy processes bounded on compact interval is linear in $t$
I know that, expect the Degenerate distribution, no probability distribution on a compact interval is  infinitely divisible.

Given a Lévy processes that is bounded on compact time intervals, I want to show that $X$ is linear in $t$, i. e. $X_t=\gamma t$.

The proof is a bit cryptic. It assumes that $X_1$ has a compact support, uses the fact above to say that there is a $\gamma$ such that $P(X_1=\gamma)=1$. Then uses the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(X_1)=0$ and stationary increments  to get $P(X_t=\gamma t)=1$ for all $t\in \mathbb{Q}^+$. And then uses right-continuity to achieve $P(X_t=\gamma t)=1$ for all $t\geq 0$.
My questions:

In the case that the support of $X_1$ isn't compact, is $\gamma=0$?
How do we use $\operatorname{Var}(X_1)=0$ in the step to get $P(X_t=\gamma t)=1$ for $t\in \mathbb{Q}^+$?

(I know how stationary increments are used)

What exactly does 'Lévy processes that is bounded on compact time intervals' mean?
